# How to configure button via UIButton.Configuration with custom SFSymbol?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I create my button:

```
private let sortButton: UIButton = {
        let buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
        let button = UIButton(configuration: buttonConfig)
        button.tintColor = R.color.controlSecondaryTypo()
        button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
        button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
        return button
    }()
```

Next I add the menu:

```
 private func setupButton() {
        let items = ["New", "Old"]

        let actions: [UIAction] = items.map {
            let action = UIAction(title: $0) { action in
                print("\(action.title)")
            }

            return action
        }

        let menu = UIMenu(options: .singleSelection, children: actions)
        sortButton.menu = menu
    }
```

Here is the display of my button

[image]

It is always displayed by default with chevron.up.chevron.down. How can I change to another SFSymbol? Example: chevron.down

I want to be able to configure button that will change the title depending on the selected UIMenu element with a custom SFSymbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you setup a UIButton with a menu and you enable the two properties `showsMenuAsPrimaryAction` and `changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction`, then the button displays the `chevron.up.chevron.down` indicator automatically to indicate that this is a popup button.

`UIButton.Configuration` has an `indicator` property that defaults to `.popup` when you setup the button as a popup button.

Since this is a standard, you should consider leaving the icon as-is since users will recognize what it is.

But if you do want to change the icon, you will need to apply your own button image and remove the indicator.

Change your button configuration code to:

```swift
var buttonConfig = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
buttonConfig.indicator = .none // Hide the standard popup icon
buttonConfig.image = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.down", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .small)) // Use the new icon
buttonConfig.imagePlacement = .trailing // Put the image after the title
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because of `UIButton.Configuration.plain()`, in current implementation I do not see any reason to init button through config, you can Button() and after add you menu.

But if you needed config then use `.borderless()`, that config might be the one you looking for.

Or make your own config by extension and play with settings of it.

Btw, if `.plain()` is required for your desires you can make something hacky, like:

```
sortButton.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIImageView })?.isHidden = true
```

but I think simple Button() or `.borderless()` would be enough

Comment: I'm not sure what question this answer is supposedly addressing. The question is asking how to change the standard up/down arrow icon of a popup button with just a `v` icon. This answer talks about changing the button style. That has nothing to do with the question. The button can use any style it wants. This answer digs into the private subviews of the button to hide the first image view. Unnecessary. Use the appropriate APIs and it's easy to achieve the desired goal.